# Woocommerce links not working on mobile phones

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working on a Wordpress site (namely, https://www.nutricionydeporteherbal.com/tienda/ ). It uses the [FitnessZone](http://support.wedesignthemes.com/article-categories/fitness-zone-wordpress-theme/) theme and a few plugins among which is WooCommerce.

My problem is that the WooCommerce search bar and the product links are not clickable in mobile mode.

Any help on this issue would be highly appreciated. :)

Just in case this information would be relevant, the full list of active plugins is:

- All 404 Redirect to Homepage 1.12
- All In One Schema Rich Snippets 1.5.2
- Antispam Bee 2.7.1
- Asesor de Cookies 0.26
- Attachment Pages Redirect 1.1
- Autoptimize 2.3.4
- Breadcrumb NavXT 6.0.4
- Broken Link Checker 1.11.5
- Coming Soon Page & Maintenance Mode by SeedProd 5.0.19
- Contact Form 7 version 5.0.1
- DesignThemes Core Features Plugin 2.2
- Envato Market 2.0.0
- Facebook Widget 4.2.2
- Google Analytics for WordPress by MonsterInsights 7.0.5
- GZip Ninja Speed Compression 1.2.3
- Imsanity 2.3.10
- kk Star Ratings 2.6.1
- LayerSlider WP 6.5.7
- Leadpages Connector 2.1.6.21
- Like This 1.6.2
- One.com themes and plugins 0.2.17
- Phoenix Media Rename 1.2.4
- Popups - WordPress Popup 1.9.2
- Really Simple SSL 2.5.26
- Recent Posts Widget With Thumbnails 6.2
- Responsive Styled Google Maps 4.3
- Slider Revolution 5.4.3.1
- Table of Contents Plus v. 1601
- Timetable Responsive Schedule For WordPress 3.9
- TranslatePress - Multilingual 1.2.2
- Unyson 2.7.12
- UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore 1.14.7
- WooCommerce 3.3.5
- WooCommerce AdWords Conversion Tracking 1.4.7
- WooCommerce Catalog Visibility Options 3.1.0
- WooCommerce Menu Cart 2.7.0
- WooCommerce PayPal Express Checkout Gateway 1.5.4
- WooCommerce Product Bundles 5.7.3
- WooCommerce Stripe Gateway 4.1.3
- Wordfence Security 7.1.4
- WP-Optimize 2.2.4
- WPBakery Visual Composer 5.2.1
- YITH WooCommerce Wishlist 2.2.1
- Yoast SEO 7.4.2

Comment: please check my answer and replay your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove float:none; from css in below css.

responsive.css (Line: 953)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
#primary.page-with-left-sidebar, #primary.page-with-right-sidebar, #primary.page-with-both-sidebar {
    display: table-caption;
    /* float: none; */
}
```

Hope this works for you.